# Windows virtual box with ubuntu unable to boot

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I have virtual box on my windows 7 professional installed with ubuntu (don't remember the exact version); When I try to boot up my clone, I get following message:

```
lvmetad is not active yet, using direct activation during sysinit
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root contains a file system with errors, check forced.
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root:
Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found

/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY.
     (i.e., without -a or -p options)
fsck exited with status code 4
The root filesystem on /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root requires a manual fsck

BusyBox v1.22.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.22.0-15ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

 (initramfs)
```

I tried googling for solutions but all the solutions suggest using 'SUDO' and performing a set of actions - BUT, my issue is I'm not even able to get to the terminal in Ubuntu! Has anyone else faced this issue and solved it?

```
Note: When the window first comes up, it shows 
  GNU GRUB version 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.18

   Ubuntu
   *Advanced options for Ubuntu
   Memory test (memtest86+)
   Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)


  Use the up and down keys to select which entry is highlighted.
  Press enter to boot the selected OS, 'e' to edit the commands
  before booting or 'c' for a command-line
```

Comment: The answer provided (2nd answer) provided here fixed my issue: https://askubuntu.com/questions/697190/fsck-error-on-boot-dev-sda6-unexpected-inconsistency-run-fsck-manually

Comment: And that is the right forum for this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I performed the following steps:

```
  fsck /dev/sda6

  And enter Yes (y) to for each error.
```

I rebooted and everything is fine.

Answer (score 2):

1. Type **fsck /dev/sda1** (depends on the drive infected "sda1,sda2 etc").
2. Repeat the fsck command if there were errors.
3. Press **yes** when prompted
4. Type **reboot** to restart the system